# for loop not printing output of array

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am brand new to Xcode and swift and following a iOS video tutorial where the teacher is discussing for loops.

> my code

```
let names = ["Chris", "John", "Steven", "Big Ralph"]

for name in names

{
    print ("Hi \(name)")

}
```

Problem: When I run the loop using Xcode 7.2 it shows (4times)in the playground but I can only see "Hi Big Ralph" as the printed output and not any of the other names in the array. Why is this.

[image]

Comment: thanks. that resolved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the view and click on "Value History"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can press the button here to see the console log:

[image]

It is in the console log

[image]